# Connecting Dlink DSL-G604T to a wireless router

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a D-link G604T and I want to connect it to a wireless main internet router (Huawei HG659).

The D-link is connected to my Windows computer via LAN Ethernet.

Can this be done?
If yes then how?

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sure it can be done.  Plug an Ethernet cable from one of the four 10/100Mbps LAN ports on the DSL-G604T to one of the four gigabit LAN ports on the Huawei HG659.

I am guessing the Huawei HG659 is what your ISP provided.  So, in the settings of the DSL-G604T make sure to disable DHCP.

Then with them both powered off, turn on the power to the DSL-G604T and give it time to fully boot.  Then turn on the power to the Huawei HG659.